# Is it good practice to unit test properties?

Tags: unit-testing

I'm still getting to grips with the whole TDD concept. Should I be writing tests for properties? Should one only write tests on properties containing sufficient logic? Any thoughts or examples on this would be great.

Comment: can you elaborate on what you mean with properties? and what is properties with logic?
as a general rule; if a method contain logic that can go wrong, it is worth unit testing, is a trade off if the creation of unit tests will cost you much time or not (in general i find that unit tests saves me time, but there are different opinions on this)

Comment: It's not really good practice to have properties at all. If a method does nothing, why does it exist? Why are other classes asking this class for its field values, rather than telling it to do things using its field values? Have a read of http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-09-2003/jw-0905-toolbox.html - getters and setters are not universally evil, but they are wildly overused, so when you find yourself asking whether something is so simple it shouldn't be tested, instead ask whether something is so simple it shouldn't even exist.

Comment: Tom@ That seems a somewhat controversial comment and flies in the face of encapsulation. Are you really advocating not having props at all, or do you just mean with reference to testing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writing a test for public getter of a private field will not give you much if this getter does nothing except returning your private field. But if it does contain some logic (or just something that can fail, like converting your private Int32 field to Byte), testing such property starts to make sense.

Comment: ok so if it checked a range say, you'd be inclinded to write a test for it?

Comment: It depends on how exactly you check your range. If there is a chance your range check can fail (index out of range, null pointer exception, or whatever you can possibly wish) - write a test, if you're not sure - write a test, eventually you're the one responsible for your code :)

Answer (score 4):

Test things that have a reasonable chance of failure - you gain no extra confidence by testing properties with no logic beyond get/set.

Comment: A prop I have in mind checks a value range i.e. >6 <12. Should something this trivial be tested in pursuit of good practice, or would this be deemed to granular?

Comment: You're not testing "the property" there though, you're testing some specific logic/requirement is met so that seems fine. It's only trivial until something breaks it.

Comment: There is no such thing as 'too granular'. The point is always to balance test writing effort with the gain in project robustness. A property that is nominally `int` but actually restricted to a subrange of that type is highly special and fragile and should *absolutely* be backed by a thorough test.

Comment: Dave - Appologies if I seem a little confussed. If the private getter for instance of the property requires a value to be within a certain range, is this not testing the property, or an aspect of it?

Comment: @Kilian - agreed. The economics should be "writing the test was worth my higher confidence in code correctness and evolution".

Answer (score 4):

Simple rule of thumb I use when doing TDD: always write tests that fail.

If a test fails at first it's a good test for TDD. It means something is not yet implemented, or not implemented as it should be. Then you can change code to make it pass. A test that succeeds at first is a bad test. You don't even know if it succeeded because you made some mistake writing the test, or because what you are testing is already working.

If you are able to produce a test failure using properties, then write tests for those properties. Typically you should begin by writing a test testing a setter or a getter before implementing it. A not implemented setter or getter can look trivial but makes test fail. And why would you write any line of code even a setter or getter if it's not **driven** by a test failure ?

Other kinds of tests, like tests as documentation showing how to use an API are also very useful, and good agile practice, but that is not TDD. TDD is about trying **actively** to break the code until you can't any more. Then you run functional tests and if you pushed unit tests hard enough, and if there is not some integration or system problem going into the way, all should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

I usually write junit tests for accessors. It doesn't add much when they're written, except to keep coverage statistics pretty. But if someone adds "sufficient logic" later to the production code, the tests will already be in place to catch any mistakes.

Also it is the work of moments to write a test to check the value returned by a getter.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of thinking of them as tests, think of each test as an example of how someone could use your code.

Instead of just testing properties, think about the behaviour which changes when the properties have different values, and give an example of the behaviour of the class in each meaningful context.

If it's really just a data property you can test by inspection, or with automated acceptance tests, or manually, maybe with a tester's help. Otherwise, don't worry about testing each method, or each property - just show how you can use the code and how you expect it to behave.

Answer (score 0):

Think of TDD and Unit testes as a way to "see ahead", you write the test in a way that you feel would be best for your public signature, of your classes, to be.